# pass SelectOneMenu value to add function in JSF / Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, schedule

i'm using primefaces schedule , when the dialog form pop up ,  i need to select data from SelectOneMenu and pass them to the add function in order to insert them into database 
the problem is that sometimes it works great and i can insert them, but when i try to add another second  insert i doesn't work again 
can you check it out please ? i need to know if i'm doing this the wrong way because i can't find the problem.

Managedbean constructor :

```
 @PostConstruct
        public void init() {


          Chauffeurs = new ArrayList<Chauffeur>();
          ChauffeurDispo = new dao.gsVoyage().getChauffeursDesponible(Chauffeurs);


          model = new DefaultScheduleModel();
          vDao=new dao.gsVoyage();
          voyage=new Voyage();
          try {
              listVoyage=vDao.getListVoyages();
          }catch(Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
              FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"erreur","erreur no sql"));
          }
          for(Voyage v:listVoyage) {
              DefaultScheduleEvent evt=new DefaultScheduleEvent();
              evt.setEndDate(v.getDateV());
              evt.setStartDate(v.getDateV());
              evt.setDescription(v.getChauffeurBean().getMatricule());
              evt.setData(v.getIdVoyage());
              model.addEvent(evt);

          }
      }
```

the add function :

```
public void ajouter() {


                        try {
                            new dao.gsVoyage().addVoyage(dateV, autocar, chauffeur,chauffeur2,0);

                                  DefaultScheduleEvent evt=new DefaultScheduleEvent();
                                  evt.setEndDate(dateV);
                                  evt.setStartDate(dateV);
                                  evt.setDescription(chauffeur);
                                  model.addEvent(evt);


                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", e.getMessage()));
                        }


                    voyage = new Voyage();

            }
```

xhtml of SelectOneMenu  :

```
                          <label>Chauffeur  :</label><br/>

                                 <h:selectOneMenu 

                                    value="#{scheduleJava8View.chauffeur}">
                                    <f:selectItems
                                        value="#{scheduleJava8View.chauffeurDispo}"
                                        var="chauffeur" itemValue="#{chauffeur.matricule}"
                                        itemLabel="#{chauffeur.nom}" />
                                            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

this is how i display inserted data in xhtml

```
<label>Chauffeur:</label><br/>
                          <p:inputText value="#{scheduleJava8View.voyage.chauffeurBean.matricule}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this

```
<h:selectOneMenu 
        onchange="submit()" 
        value="#{scheduleJava8View.chauffeur}">
```

This will make a call to

```
setChauffeur(Chauffeur c)
```

on your backed bean. Notice that in this case, you will need to define a [converter](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jsf/custom-converter.html) since it is not a Java basic type (int, String,...).

Comment: Sorry, but this is an answer how things were done 15-20 years ago. With the introduction of ajax this was not dome anymore.

Comment: You are right. I was just answering the question and assuming that s/he was not using ajax. For sure Ajax is far better than this :)

Comment: Hmmm... why not answer with an ajax related solution then? If OP is not using the 2020 ajax solution and is not using 2000 submit solution, wouldn't suggestion for a 2020 solution better